# Error while uploading image to server in base 64encoding string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, asihttprequest

I'm trying to upload data onto a server. The server can accept strings of images. Now I'm using the following code to upload image to the server.

```
NSData *image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString* pictureDataString = [image base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];
[_request setPostValue:pictureDataString forKey:@"media"];
```

But I'm getting the following error. Can anyone please help me out here.

```
"(<class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadValueError'>, BadValueError('Property media must be convertible to a Blob instance (Blob() argument should be str instance, not unicode)',), <traceback object at 0x69a1cd63d506f800>)"
```

Comment: are you trying to send your image in base 64encoding string.

Comment: yes.. i m tryoing to send it as.

Comment: what is your base64EncodingWithLineLength function doing?

Comment: I think the problem is in your pictureDataString.Put a nslog and see what are you getting in pictureDataString.

Comment: Use useful headlines! Please!

Comment: @gypsa. dont know just added NSData+base64.h and it has that function built in.. and it is returning a full encoded string..

Comment: Why are you using base 64 on your image? POST request uses delimiters . It seems overkill to me.

Comment: Have you tried using the max line length ([image base64EncodingWithLineLength:76]) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use..

```
    NSData *image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [_request setPostValue:image for key:"media";
```

it will work.